# How to import a 3d object (.obj) into LEA extended input resource manager

Tags: 3d

I am trying to import a 3d object into LEA extended input software so that I can use it in in the 3d model of the project editor.
This is the tutorial but I cannot understand how to get it working
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=00PRoYmUYkk

Problem in a glimpse: I dont see any 3d object in the select 3d model windows

Answer (score 0):

you need to first open the resources manager (click on the Tray bar icon) then select / create a game, then select the "Resources" tab (then click on add just under the Resources list (second "row") then click on the resource you just created and finally select "mesh" in the "type" drop down button (last "row).

Now open a LEA project, then add with a drag&drop a "3D model" then right click on background, then select "edit parameter", then open "3D renderer", scroll down till you see the "add 3D model" button click on it and then click on "select" button in front of 3D model.

There is some trick:
- the model is rotated from the 3D object center, so you need to check that the 3D model center is where you want it to be.

other thing is some time you wont see any thing because the scale of your mesh is too big so you need to play a little with the Scale mormaly it's between 0.3 to 5

if you want to configure an action when you touch the 3D model go in edit mode and then right click on the model.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but there is a problem

When I click on select in front of the 3D Model, I don't see the object I imported into the resource

I have edited my question to post the picture.

Comment: can you share your model ? so I can try

Comment: here is the .obj file
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1drDgxmOj0fzNLhl-ak6dfvIs8RtSQ8ZB?usp=sharing

Comment: @mani shekar the file is corrupted, there is references to a material but there isn't any materials defined in the .obj and the file is too big, use Meshlab [link](http://www.meshlab.net/) to clean the mesh and make it a little smaller less than 60000 face. you can split the mesh in various part too. like that it will be smaller and more interactive too